# Solr return all results when q=<empty>

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, solr, codeigniter-url

I am using **PHP Codeigniter framework** with [**solr-php-client**](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) to build a search application.

I have two pages -

1. a search page with just a single input box
2. a results page which will display results when user enters a search term in search page

The issue is, unless I enter a search term [**solr-php-client**](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) is not returning any results and for which the url would just be `"http://localhost:8080/search/?q="` and it wont do anything. But when I enter a search term such as "apple" as an eg., it redirect to results page with matching results without any issue and the url becomes `"http://localhost:8080/rdsearch/?q=apple"`

What I would like to achieve is - When user **does not** enter a search term in the search page or when q is empty as in `"http://localhost:8080/search/?q="`, it should simply direct to results page and show all the results (similar to a solr query `*:*`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some other solutions available, I can propose you the following 2 solutions.

1. You can check your input box. If it's empty, by default pass `*:*` as input with the Solr URL.
2. Or you can modify your **solrconfig.xml** for the **select** request handler. Put

> `<str name="q.alt">*:*</str>`

While querying

> http://'localhost':8080/solr/collection1/select?q=&wt=xml&indent=true&**defType=dismax**

You can see though I've provided `q=` , but it'll return all the result. Because it'll take the q.alt query as the query parser is Dismax now. For further info please [read here](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser)

Comment: Thanks! I checked my solrconfig.xml and I see q.alt is set to '*:*' already and I am not sure why it is being ignored in solr-php-client (http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) that I am using.

Comment: On top of this, also I had to edit my controller file in codeigniter to include if $q is empty, it has to return everything